# FileMaker Pro PHP ODBC Connection

Tags: php, odbc, filemaker

How do I connect to a FMP database using an ODBC connection?
The name of the server is fmserver, and there is no Username or Password.
This is what I try:

```
$name = 'fmserver';
$conn = odbc_connect($name, '', '');
```

But for some reason, when I try it out, it brings me to a page that says (on chrome):

> Server error
>
> The website encountered an error while retrieving [URL]. It may be
>   down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Is there some method that I'm implementing wrong? I have the IP address too, and have tried that, but I can't seem to get that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the FileMaker ODBC driver installed and configured with "fmserver" as the DSN?

I would highly recommend you take a look at the FileMaker PHP API vs. ODBC.

http://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/php.html